# Parsed String of Dates not formatting properly in facelet

Tags: jsf, facelets

Data I am provided comes from a database view.  One column contains a lists of comma separated dates, because the dates come from a one-to-many table join. So now I am stuck parsing and formating in my jsf facelet.

```
 <ui:repeat value="#{chartController.reportData}" var="c" >
   <tr>
  ...other columns
     <td>
     <ui:repeat value="#{fn:split(c[41], ',')}" var="date">
        <h:outputText value="#{date}" >
             <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
        </h:outputText><br />
     </ui:repeat>
     </td>
    </tr>
 </ui:repeat>



 public List<String> getReportData() {
     return reportData;
 }
```

However, the date is not formatting properly, it displays as `30-OCT-11` but I need it to be `11/30/2011`  The f:convertDateTime works properly when I work on a single value that does not need to be parsed.

Comment: Looks like the `date` variable is interpreted as `String`. You could have a `List<Date>` on your JSF managed bean and bind it to your `<ui:repeat>` (it will be easier to handle).

Comment: My backing bean is just returing a List of Strings. And then I am referencing by column number, i.e., #{c[41]} I edited my post to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<f:convertDateTime>` converts from a `java.util.Date` instance to `String` in given pattern during rendering HTML output and from `String` in given pattern to a `java.util.Date` instance during processing the form submit. It does not convert `String` in pattern X to another `String` in pattern Y.

The root cause of your problem is in having a rather poor data model with everything stringified. Perhaps you used `ResultSet#getString()` all the way instead of `ResultSet#getObject()`. Also, one-to-many relationships shouldn't be represented as a commaseparated string, but as a collection or array property.

E.g. this model representing a single record:

```
public class ReportDataItem {

    private List<Date> dates;

    // ...
}
```

which is referenced as follows:

```
public List<ReportDataItem> getReportData() {
    return reportData;
}
```

and presented as follows:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{chartController.reportData}" var="reportDataItem" >
    ...other columns
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ui:repeat value="#{reportDataItem.dates}" var="date">
                <h:outputText value="#{date}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                </h:outputText>
                <br />
            </ui:repeat>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC.  I'll look at improving my model.  Originally client only wanted sum aggregates of data and charts drawn, so I used just an array.  But now they want the backing data and I just went with my original array of string appraoch.  The IT dept provides me the data as a view and they do all the table joining and cram the one to many as comma separated values in one field and make me parse it.  I got to get out of this company!!!